# How to inject a controller into a directive when unit-testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, controller, directive

I want to test an AngularJS directive declared like this

```
app.directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      template: 'cust.html'
      controller: 'customerController'
    };
  });
```

In the test I would like to inject (or override) the controller, so that I can test just the other parts of the directive (e.g. the template). The `customerController` can of course be tested separately. This way I get a clean separation of tests.

- I have tried overriding the controller by setting the controller property in the test.
- I have tried injecting the `customController` using `$provide`.
- I have tried setting `ng-controller` on the html directive declaration used in the test.

I couldn't get any of those to work. The problem seems to be that I cannot get a reference to the directive until I have `$compile`d it. But after compilation, the controller is already set up.

```
 var element = $compile("<my-customer></my-customer>")($rootScope);
```

Comment: Can you please show your spec and the code you've tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a simpler way than the accepted answer, which doesn't require creating a new module.

You were close when trying `$provide`, but for mocking controllers, you use something different: `$controllerProvider`. Use the `register()` method in your spec to mock out your controller.

```
beforeEach(module('myApp', function($controllerProvider) {
    $controllerProvider.register('customerContoller', function($scope) {
        // Controller Mock
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Although my answer is a viable alternative, this approach is much better. (It was more than a year back; my ng-fu was lame :)) Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/JPJsp/22/) should anyone want to see @fiznool's approach in action.

Answer (score 10):

One way is to define a new module (e.g. 'specApp') that declares your app (e.g. 'myApp') as a dependency. Then register a 'customerController' controller with the 'specApp' module. This will effectively "hide" the customerController of 'myApp' and supply this mock-controller to the directive when compiled.
E.g.:

Your **app**:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
...
app.controller('customerController', function ($scope,...) {
    $scope = {...};
    ...
});
app.directive('myCustomer', function () {
    return {
        template: 'cust.html',
        controller: 'customerController'
    };
});
```

Your **spec**:

```
describe('"myCustomer" directive', function () {
    $compile;
    $newScope;

    angular.module('specApp', ['myApp'])
    /* Register a "new" customerController, which will "hide" that of 'myApp' */
    .controller('customerController', function ($scope,...) {
        $scope = {...};
        ...
    });

    beforeEach(module('specApp'));

    it('should do cool stuff', function () {
        var elem = angular.element('<div my-customer></div>');
        $compile(elem)($newScope);
        $newScope.$digest();
        expect(...
    });
});
```

---

See, also, this **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/JPJsp/)**.