# How to inject dependencies to a named angular directive controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, bundling-and-minification

If I have code similar to [this question on injecting another controller to a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252295/how-to-inject-a-controller-to-a-directive-in-another-module):

```
angular.module('paramApp', []);

angular.module('paramApp').controller('ParamCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   .
   .
   .
}]);

angular.module('deviceApp', ['paramApp']);
angular.module('deviceApp').directive('DeviceDirective', function () {    
    return { 
    .
    .
    .
    controller: 'ParamCtrl' 
    };
});
```

When I minify js, the injected dependencies of `$scope` and `$http` break, how can I explicitly define the dependencies of `ParamCtrl` when creating `DeviceDirective` to prevent [uncaught injector issues with bundled js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671962/uncaught-error-injectorunpr-with-angular-after-deployment)?

Answer (score 1):

I am very late to this question but I'll give it a shot.
The syntax is based on [John Papa's Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

First you need a way to make your controller reusable. Convert it from an anonymous function to a named function and pass it to your angular app like so:

```
// Named controller function
ParamCtrl function($scope, $http) {
   this.doStuff
}

// Bind it to your app
angular.module('paramApp').controller('ParamCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', ParamCtrl );

// While we are at it, do the same with your directive
DeviceDirective function (controlerParam) {    
    return { 
        ...
        controller: controlerParam
    } 
}

// Bind it to your app
angular.module('deviceApp', ['ParamCtrl', DeviceDirective]);
```

However, if you meant to pass the controller's scope to your directive refer to [fiznool's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28628512/4775223)